# How do I get the App Engine Discovery document for my API?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm watching a video tutorial title "[Google I/O 2012 - Building Mobile App Engine Backends...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=NU_wNR_UUn4#t=1219)" and at 20:20 (click link it will take you there) he mentions the discovery document. How do I get the same App Engine Discovery document for my API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the Discovery Document for your API class via the Endpoints command line tool. Check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool) for generating the Discovery doc.

Comment: Would you happen to know if there is a way to do this from the eclipse google app engine plugin?

Comment: Right click on the Project, then Google -> Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library. The discovery documents will get generated in the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Thank you. This helped. They have have .discovery extension and they were created for both rest and rpc.